# Looping code in java

Tags: java, loops

I have written code that will record all of my information in another code to a textfile.  However I know i havent been able to advance the variable 'u' properly and I'm not sure how to do so.

```
public void writeAllToFile()
  {
    try
    {
      BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("SystemData.txt"));
      int i =0;
      String u = emailUsers.getUser(i).username;
      while(u!=null)
      {
        bw.write("" + emailUsers.getUser(i).username);
        bw.newLine();
        bw.write(""+emailUsers.getUser(i).inbox.getNumMessages());
        bw.newLine();
        int j=0;
        String s = emailUsers.getUser(i).inbox.getMessage(j).getSender();
        while(s!=null)
        {
          bw.write("" + emailUsers.getUser(i).inbox.getMessage(j).getSender());
          bw.newLine();
          bw.write("" + emailUsers.getUser(i).inbox.getMessage(j).getReceiver());
          bw.newLine();
          bw.write("" + emailUsers.getUser(i).inbox.getMessage(j).getSubject());
          bw.newLine();
          bw.write("" + emailUsers.getUser(i).inbox.getMessage(j).getBody());
          bw.newLine();
          j++;
        }
        i++;
      }
      bw.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    }
  }
```

Comment: " been able to advance the u" . Do you want to advance U?

Comment: Also, you're swallowing all exceptions. Don't do that.

Comment: Didn't you just ask this question? Or was that someone else with basically the same exact code?

Comment: @Human: do you have a link to the previous similar question?

Comment: Your question has precisely nothing to do with BufferedWriter, and everything to do with the undisclosed API 'emailUsers.getUser()'. I don't understand how you can expect an answer when you don't tell us how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Variable `u` is set only once outside the while-loop, adding `u = emailUsers.getUser(i).username;` right after `i++;` in the end of the loop should help.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to give more info, i could help you better if you tell me what kind of object is emailUsers or what kind of object return the method getUser(int i).

meanwhile, may be this works:

`int i =0;
String u = "";
while((u=emailUsers.getUser(i).username)!=null){}`